# Can't select view controller or cells on iPad simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

I'll try to keep this short and sweet. I have a universal storyboard and my application runs perfectly on the iPhone. I'm having an issue though where I have a view controller with 2 containers, which contain separate tableviewcontrollers.

On the iPad simulator the top table view controller works fine yet the bottom will not scroll or select any cells. Again, it works perfectly on the iPhone simulator.

I cannot for the life of my figure out whats causing this. Anyone run into something similar?

Thanks

Comment: Every time I ran into this issue, it turned out to be because I had inadvertently added an invisible view that was catching all the touches. Make sure your top table view controller doesn't have an invisible portion that's catching the touches intended for the bottom view controller. An easy way to check is to set the `backgroundColor` of the top view controller to see if it then covers the bottom one.

Comment: In the Simulator you could use : Debug -> Color Blended Layers to check is that has some layers show on your view

Comment: They appear identical so I'm not sure. Also if I select the background of the bottom TVC, I can drag and scroll but thats about it. The cells are non responsive
http://i61.tinypic.com/dgpgl2.png

Comment: I thought the same thing as Eric. It sounds like you've got a view covering part or all of your table view and interfering with touches. Try pulling down the debug menu, selecting "View Debugging", and selecting "Capture View Hierarchy" Once you've done that you can drag to rotate the view hierarchy and it gives you a 3D exploded diagram of your views, shown stacked in Z order. It's a powerful way to figure out mysteries like this.

Comment: You could also look here for ways to see what is going on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28581546/only-first-link-is-detected-in-uitextview/28584674#28584674

Answer (score 0):

Your view might be covered by another view. To make sure your view stays in the front, you can use

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:yourView];
```